# Connecting HP Officejet 6100 to WiFi; Technicolor TC8715D router rejects correct password from printer and some other devices

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I am troubleshooting my mom's home WiFi network. She has a Technicolor TC8715D router. Intermittently, her iPhone (8?) or her iPad get kicked off the WiFi. When she re-enters the correct password she gets an "incorrect password" message, even though my iPhone (and Windows 7 PC) are connected to the same network with the same password, no problems.

I thought this was an issue with my mom's iOS devices, but today I'm having a similar problem connecting an HP Officejet 6100 to the network. While going through the install wizard I checked "Wireless - Connect the printer to your wireless network and internet." The wizard then prompted me to "temporarily connect a USB cabel to enable wireless setup". After some time, it says "Setup can attempt to access your computer or router to retrieve and store your SSID and password" and prompted me to choose between:

- Yes, access the computer or router.
- No, I will enter the settings manually.

Either choice eventually leads to the following error:

```
Your printer failed to join the wireless network. 
Issue: Incorrect wireless password.
Solution: The WPA security passphrase you configured on your HP printer does 
not match the WPA passphrase used by the wireless router.  Configure the printer
using the correct WPA passphrase.
```

I know that I'm using the correct passphrase because I have multiple devices connected to this network. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You should consider someone else near by is using the same SSID, or maybe you have a wireless extender/repeater that is misconfigured?

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with this particular router but here are some possible problems to look into. Also, I am assuming that when you say, "password," you are referring to the encryption key (i.e. WPA, WPA2, WEP, etc.).

1. Reboot the router and devices
2. On the router, check the following:

   - If there is a maximum number of connections allowed (if so, increase number or disable feature)
   - If MAC address filtering is enables (if enable, either disable or enter the MAC address of acceptable devices into the router).    - Does the router use the exact same wireless key (note, capitalization matters; do not use spaces) for both bands (2.4Ghz. 5Ghz) of the router? If not, I recommend making them match.
   - Does the router use the exact same encryption method (e.g. WEP, WPA, WPA2) for both bands? If not, I suggest to change them both to the same (WPA2 ideally).
   - Is the SSID hidden (default is usually visible)? If it is, make visible (at least during connecting new devices).
   - Are there different SSID names for different bands (2.4, 5 GHz)? They can be the same or different; however, when troubleshooting, it can sometimes be beneficial to rename one of the bands to a different SSID to see if it help reveal problems/solutions. I am unsure if the printer supports 5Ghz band so having different SSID will help determine if the printer can connect on both frequencies.
   - If the router has a WPS button to connect new devices, enable this feature in the router.
3. When entering the key into a wireless device (iPhone, printer, etc.), be sure to do the following:

   - First, delete/remove the network (SSID) from the devices before retrying. For the printer, you may want to go through its menu and reset everything to factory default before trying again.
   - Search for SSID you want to connect to (If you enter the SSID manually, note the capitalization matters and there can be no spaces). Note, the iphone does not support WPS connection method but the HP printer may. If the printer can connect via WPS, first press the WPS button on router and then the WPS button on printer (the printers "WPS button" is likely a menu option under connections. If you don't want to use WPS, proceed to manually entry.
   - Select the same encryption method used by router (e.g. WEP, WPA, WPA2)
   - Be sure to match the key exactly (e.g. no spaces, capitalization matters); make sure you don't confuse letter and numbers that look similar (e.g. "1" vs lowercase L) when entering or having trailing/leading spaces.
4. If you are still having problems, make sure the devices aren't too far from the router as the signal weakens with distance and obstacles (e.g. walls). Further, 5GHz cannot travel as far as 2.4GHz and will weaken quicker. So, selecting the 2.4GHz SSID may yield better results.
5. If these don't help, you are stuck in one of those situations we all find ourselves in where we keep starting from scratch trying to make the connection until for some unexplained reason it finally connects or we go insane. Seriously though, one of the above issues usually is the reason for a connection problem.
6. Clean-up and security. After everything is working, I recommend the following:

   - In the router settings, disable the WPS button for security purposes
   - Hide the SSID - again, helps tighten security (but will likely need to be made visible again if you want to attach new devices).
   - If you are an advanced user, you might want to consider MAC address filtering for added security. If you aren't an advanced user, it can cause more headaches and might be worth leaving alone.
   - If you are security conscious, I suggest disable any guest networks and ensure the wireless encryption key you use is at least 16 characters long with random letters (both capital and lowercase), numbers, and symbols (but no spaces). Such a password would need to be written down somewhere safe and would be a headache to enter ... but, it ups your network security.

Hope something in here helps.

Answer (score 0):

A firmware update was made available from HP in july 2020 that fixes this issue (at least for my 5 year old HP Deskjet 2540 series printer).

Connect with USB, install the firmware update and try setting up wifi again (my even worked without setting up wifi again, as the settings I tried previously apparantly were saved).